# What can be the use case for Spring bean idref?

Tags: spring, ioc-container, idref

I know that `idref` is used to pass the id of a bean (i.e String value but not the reference). I was asked in an interview, what can be the use case of `idref`? Why and when it should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idref` just adds a layer of security by validating at deployment time that the referenced, named bean actually exists.

[A very nice example with appropriate explanation is provided in this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-idref-element)

**Example**

```
<bean id="abc" class="..."/>

<bean id="xyz" class="...">
  <property name="abcName">
      <idref bean="abc" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

can also be written as

```
<bean id="abc" class="..." />

<bean id="xyz" class="...">
  <property name="abcName" value="abc" />
</bean>
```

The advantage of using first way is already described.

If you use the second method then no validation is performed on the value that is passed to the `abcName` property of the `xyz` bean i.e. during the loading of the context.

Errors are only discovered when the `xyz` bean is instantiated. So, we can never know if any typos have been injected by the developer during the instantiation phase.

**Note :** *It is just a recommended approach, not a mandatory approach*

Comment: As explained by @ItachiUchiha in the first line of this answer, whenever you wish to validate that a named bean exists before it is injected.

Comment: What other than just validation? I know it's for validation